# Plotly.graph_objects map, how to update range_color property?

Tags: python, plotly

This is my map and I made the countries from green to red by tax rate,
but color range is 0 to 200 now how can i change this property?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

colorscale = ["rgb(0, 255, 0)", "rgb(255, 165, 0)", "rgb(255, 0, 0)"]

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations=df_taxes['Country'],
    locationmode='country names',
    z=df_taxes['Total tax rate'],
    colorscale=colorscale,
    colorbar=dict(title='Vergi Oranı'),
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
    locationmode='country names',
    locations=df_taxes['Country'],
    text=df_taxes['Total tax rate'],
    mode='text',
    textposition='top center',
    showlegend=False
))


fig.update_layout(
    margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

I need just color_range code by graph objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
    
colorscale = ["rgb(0, 255, 0)","rgb(255, 165, 0)", "rgb(255, 0, 0)"]
    
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations=df_taxes['Country'],
    locationmode='country names',
    z=df_taxes['Total tax rate'],
    colorscale=colorscale,
    colorbar=dict(title='Vergi Oranı'),
    zmin=0, #zmin and zmax.
    zmax=100
))
    
fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
    locationmode='country names',
    locations=df_taxes['Country'],
    text=df_taxes['Total tax rate'],
    mode='text',
    textposition='top center',
    showlegend=False
))

fig.update_layout(
    margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
)

fig.show()
```